# How to refere to tfvc from a git repo triggerd build in visual studio online

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are migrating to git and have some powershell scripts that worked properly with tfvc, but fail during a git repo triggerd build.

The reason for that is that the tfvc is not accessible in the "Script path field", as it used to be trough `$\TeamName\..\..\..`

The build agent seems to look at the build path instead of tfvc when the dollar sign reference is used. e.g. :`Invalid file path 'D:\a\1\s\$\..\..etc`

Am I overlooking something or are the only possible solutions

1. Nuget package it, and restore during build
2. Or include the script in the git repo?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What value are you entering for the script path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use Powershell scripts but don't want to include them in the git repository because they are used by multiple build definitions(cross repo). You can use the the in-line Powershell task type.

To circumvent the limitation of 5000 characters, use f12 to change the max size of the field. It is just a ui "limitation".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a build definition, you can either select a Git source or a TFVC source, check the screenshot below:

[image]

If you choose a Git source, you are not able to access a TFVC source. So you can either select TFVC source as before, or import all resources that the build need to a repo and select Git source. For the latter, you can refer to [import a repo from TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-from-tfvc?view=vsts), then you can select the correct script path in the Powershell task.